# Creating link with html content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper

I would like to create some HTML helper functions to create some links with generated HTML content. I would follow the default API as much as possible. This gets tricky when I want to pass in a routevalues object. A routevalue object of type `RouteValueDictionary` is (intentionally?) cumbersome to create in MVC. I would like to pass in an `object routevalues` as is done with i.e. `Html.ActionLink`. The tricky part is that I seem to need `UrlHelper.CreateUrl` which requires a `RouteValueDictionary`. I checked how `ActionLink` does this internally, and it uses `TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary`. `TypeHelper` however is an internal class, so I can't access that. I could copy-paste the thing in, but - apart from that firstly i'd be violating the license if I do that and don't license under the Apache 2.0 license or compatible, and secondly copy-paste programming gives me the heeby-jeebies.

The following is what I'd roughly like to do:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyFancyActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper,
                                              Foo foo,
                                              object routevalues){
  TagBuilder inner = fancyFooContent(foo);
  RouteValueDictionary routedict = TypeHelper.ObjectToDictionary(routevalues);
  //alas! TypeHelper is internal!
  string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null,
                                     "myaction",
                                     "mycontroller",
                                     routedict,
                                     helper.ViewContext.RequestContext,
                                     true);
  TagBuilder link = new TagBuilder("a");
  link.MergeAttribute("href", url);
  link.InnerHtml = inner.toString();
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(link.ToString());
}
```

Comment: can you update your version? https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1737

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RouteValueDictionary has a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc680272%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an object and uses its properties to populate the dictionary. Unless I am missing something obvious here, you should be able to use that:

```
RouteValueDictionary routedict = new RouteValueDictionary(routevalues);
```

Comment: I should. I have no idea how I missed that.